# the CJK support suddenly no longer works when using latexmk to render the pdf

Tags: latexmk, xecjk

I am using this command to compile the latex(2023 live) document in MacBook Pro with M1 pro chip:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode
```

when I change the document content, will trigger the document recompile immediately and refresh the pdf in Skim `Version 1.6.16 (146)`. Sometimes I found that after the rerender, the CJK font are no longer rendered in pdf, only contains the ascii charactor. this is the document looks like:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{book}


\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=4]{hyperref}

\setCJKmainfont{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}

你好! Hi!

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your document (MacOS 12.6.7, TeXLive 2023), xelatex gives an error that `Font TU/NotoSerifCJKSC(0)/m/n/10="Noto Serif CJK SC/OT" at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.`  If I comment out the `\setCJKmainfont` line, things seem to work fine.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to supply both the `-pdfxe` and `-xelatex` options to latexmk.  Just using one or the other is sufficient.  But using both won't cause problems.

Comment: I have installed this fonts `Noto Serif CJK SC` in my local mac book.